# Open page/post/product only when user is logged in - WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm setting up a new Wordpress site, which is using the WP Job Manager. I need some help with the code to create a compulsory login to view the single job posts once clicked.

I have tried using some plug-ins as well as Googled some code, but none of them seem to work.

```
<?php   
    add_action( 'single_job_listing', 'login_to_view_job_listing' );

    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {  
    'else';
    wp_die;
        return home_url( '/account-login/?redirect_to=' . $redirect );
    'endif'; 
}
```

I copied this into the content_single-job_listing.php file. It has done nothing to the site, the page still opens without requiring the user to login.

Comment: In your job detail page check with ` is_user_logged_in()` this is used to check user is logged in or not

Comment: Hi dipmala, I have made a change to the code. It is still not working, please let me know if you can see any errors?

Answer (score -1):

Call following function and check the output if not empty then pass else redirect to login page

```
$userDetails = get_current_user_id();

If(!$userDetails){
  // Redirect to login page
}
```

Comment: I have added in the above code, but it is not making a difference to the page, it still opens without redirecting to the accounts page.

Comment: try using `global $user_id;` can print it and check if It is not empty